# I can't run the app: ucrtbased.dll is missing

Tags: visual-studio, dll

I built the application in visual studio. Then I decided to transfer it to a computer that doesn't have visual studio on it to see if I could run it.
I transferred the project folder to this computer.and of course I got an error about the absence of a **ucrtbased.dll**.

then I downloaded this file and threw it into system32 folder. But the error still persists and I can't run the application. How to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: ucrtbased.dll is the debug build of ucrtbase.dll.  It is only available on a machine that has VS installed.  You must only deploy the Release build of a project.

Comment: @HansPassant that is, I will not be able to test this application in any way on those computers that do not have VS, right?

Comment: @idk_how That's not what Hans said. You need to build your application in release mode before distributing it to another computer.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks